# GCP: creating private DNS in a project using subnet of a shared vpc

Tags: google-cloud-dns

I am trying to create private dns zone for a project (service project) using subnet of a shared vpc. but its not letting me to choose the subnet (dedicated for this project) which can see this zone (from add network option). arent we allowed by constraints, else what is the way out?

Comment: Could you please provide any evidences of this issue?